# Proof Errors: 4=5 Using sin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fake-proofs, paradoxes

Many fake proofs are somewhat obvious involving division by 0 for example. I've come across this one which I have not seen discussed anywhere and I'm not too sure where the error lies, if there even is one.

I'm not so good with MathJax but the opening line given is:

"4 = 5 iff 4/5 = 1" : Not sure if use of double arrow is correct.

The 'proof' is as follows:

$$ 4=5 \iff \frac{4}{5} = 1$$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{4}{5} = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
$$Let \space \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow \sin \left( \theta\right) = \frac{4}{5}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin\left(\pi - \theta\right) = \frac{4}{5}$$
$$\Rightarrow \pi - \theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) $$
$$\Rightarrow\pi - \arcsin\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) = \arcsin\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) $$
$$\Rightarrow\arcsin\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{4}{5} = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$$
$$\therefore 4 = 5$$

Is there an error with restricted domain of $\arcsin?$ Is it that there are a family of solutions when $\sin$ is introduced? Or is it just a fancy manipulation which ultimately does nothing and leaves the original statement? My gut feeling is that it's just a string of fancy ways to re-write $1$, but I'm really not sure and am therefore asking here.

What's the way to argue against this?

Comment: So one assumes $\sin\theta=4/5$ and deduces $4=5$????

Comment: you begin with the assumption that $4=5$

Comment: The first line is already false, if you assume that $4=5$ of course you'll get a bunch of nonsense. The first rule in proof writing is that you must only assume what has been previously proven.

Comment: This is what I saw posted, verbatim. The OP stands firm on 'discovering a paradox'. When challenged on the assumption his reply was 'if a=b then a/b=1' and so he is trying to show the ratio is 1. When asked why sin, he simply said because sin(pi/2) is 1. I don't know what approach is best to show him wrong. As I think I alluded to, it seems like circular reasoning.

Comment: The biggest flaw of this reasoning is very poor presentation. There is also an actual fine error (the one the mysterious OP has in mind), but it's well hidden under the confusing exposition of the proof.

Comment: The statement if $a=b$ then $a/b=1$, $a \neq 0$ is true but in this case $a \neq b$ to begin with.

Comment: @Adayah would you be so kind as to expand your comment to an answer? I'm particularly interested in the error you reference.

Comment: The said "proof" is strictly equivalent to $\quad 4=5\text{ iff }4=5\quad$.

Comment: You cannot begin a proof by assuming your conclusion.

Comment: As the title says, this whole "proof" is a sin (against math). :-)

Comment: The OP didn't even make clear which statement he is trying to "prove". If the statement is "$4=5 \Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{5}=1$", then this statement is certainly true, but it doesn't require such a complicated "proof". If the statement is "$4=5$", then this statement is certainly false, but we don't need to look for any deep errors as the "proof" immediately starts with assuming its hypothesis, and the rest of this nonsense doesn't matter.

Comment: You can start a mathematical proof with a statement that's the opposite of what you want to prove (and hence presumably untrue), then get a result that is clearly not true, and deduce that the opposite statement was false, hence original statement was true. Proof by contradiction. However this "proof" doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, the main flaw of the solution is poor exposition, which makes it difficult to find the finer, intended error. A better version of this puzzle would be:

Let $\theta = \arcsin \frac{4}{5}$ so that $\sin \theta = \frac{4}{5}$. Then also $\sin( \pi - \theta ) = \frac{4}{5}$, thus $\pi - \theta = \arcsin \frac{4}{5}$. Matching it together, we get $\theta = \pi - \theta$ so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, therefore $\frac{4}{5} = \sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$.

The obvious fallacy is drawing the conclusion that $\pi - \theta = \arcsin \frac{4}{5}$ from the equation $\sin( \pi - \theta ) = \frac{4}{5}$, since $\arcsin$ is only a partial inverse of $\sin$.

---

One could even argue I just made up the puzzle above myself, because there is so little similarity to the original puzzle in the structure of the proof. Well, I wouldn't deny.

But maybe the mess in the puzzle was intended to make it more obscure...

Comment: While I'll allow that the OP's post is hard to decipher, I think this is the only answer/comment that actually addresses the specific thing the OP is confused about.

Answer (score 0):

The 'proof' ultimately does nothing at all. It just walks around in a circle then returns to the blatantly false* claim that $4=5$. Since $\theta$ is set to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the outset, all the intermediate steps are ultimately the same** expression: $\sin{\theta}=\frac{4}{5}$. You could swap $4$ and $5$ for any two numbers you desired and the 'proof' would work exactly the same; but unless your two numbers were equal and non-zero, the 'proof' will be invalid because it would assert that $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}\neq1$ and that $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}=1$ simultaneously, which is obviously fallacious.

* Sorry Big Brother.

** If we consider $\arcsin$ to have codomain $(-\pi,\pi]$, or some other codomain which contains $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Many times in mathematics your "assumption" can be false, but it can lead to a satisfying and believing proof.

All the fake proofs start off with something false, and so whatever the result is from then on, its all gibberish, and can be true, or it can be false. We don't know.

The proper proofs assume something that is **known to be true**.

This is just another case where it just "works", but since your assumption that $4=5$ is already false from the start, the proof from then on has no meaning.